# Using knockout and trying to push some new data into the array I got undefined error. Why

Tags: methods, knockout.js, push, undefined

Im working with array **Objects** and knockout js. Some code below makes that data avaliable for binding and with that everything ok. But when Im trying to push some data in array **row** I got this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
>   ADMIN_gym_demo3.html:217

And now I cant figure out why that construction didt work.

```
Objects = {days: [
        {day: 'Monday', row:[{
                col1: '100', col2: '200', col3: '300', col4: '400', col5: '500'
            },{
                col1: '100', col2: '200', col3: '300', col4: '400', col5: '500'
            },{
                col1: '100', col2: '200', col3: '300', col4: '400', col5: '500'
            }]},{//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        day: 'Tuesday', row:[{
                col1: '100', col2: '200', col3: '300', col4: '400', col5: '500'
            },{
                col1: '100', col2: '200', col3: '300', col4: '400', col5: '500'
            },{
                col1: '100', col2: '200', col3: '300', col4: '400', col5: '500'
            }]},{//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        day: 'Wednesday', row:[{
                col1: '100', col2: '200', col3: '300', col4: '400', col5: '500'
            },{
                col1: '100', col2: '200', col3: '300', col4: '400', col5: '500'
            },{
                col1: '100', col2: '200', col3: '300', col4: '400', col5: '500'
            }]}///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ]};


var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    cont = ko.mapping.fromJS(Objects);
    alld = cont.days;
    thisrow = self.row;
    crow = alld.thisrow;

    val1 = ko.observable('');
    val2 = ko.observable('');
    val3 = ko.observable('');
    val4 = ko.observable('');
    val5 = ko.observable('');

    add = function(){

            var vm1 = val1;
            var vm2 = val2;
            var vm3 = val3;
            var vm4 = val4;
            var vm5 = val5;

            crow.push({
                col1: vm1(), col2: vm2(), col3: vm3(), col4: vm4(), col5: vm5() });
            };
    }; 

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel);
```

That how it looks with html:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: alld">
                    <p data-bind="text: day"></p>
                    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed" >        
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>time</th>
                        <th>training time</th>
                        <th>difficulty</th>
                        <th>coach</th>
                        <th>gym</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: row">

                    <tr >
                        <td data-bind="text: col1">7.00-10.00</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: col2">bodypump</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: col3">I-III</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: col4">Michael Ivanov</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: col5">01</td>
                    </tr>

                    </tbody>


                </table>

                <div style="width: 100%" >
                        <div style="display: inline; float: left; width: 20%"  >
                            <input data-bind="value: val1" />             
                        </div>                                            
                        <div style="display: inline; float: left; width: 20%">
                            <input data-bind="value: val2" />            
                        </div>                                           
                        <div style="display: inline; float: left; width: 20%">
                            <input data-bind="value: val3" />             
                        </div>                                            
                        <div style="display: inline; float: left; width: 20%">
                            <input data-bind="value: val4" />             
                        </div>                                            
                        <div style="display: inline; float: left; width: 20%">
                            <input data-bind="value: val5" />
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star" data-iconpos="right" data-mini="true" data-bind="click: add" >Add row</a>    

                </div>
```

Can somebody tell me where is my mistake? 
Here is my jsfidle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uhtshka/BWxm7/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is 'cannot call method push of undefined.'  This means that the thing you are trying to call push on is undefined.  Let's see what line of code is calling push:

```
alld.row.push(...);
```

The error message is telling you that alld.row is undefined.  So let's look and see where alld comes from to see if we can figure out why the row property on alld is undefined:

```
alld = ko.observableArray();
alld = Objects.days;
```

It's first made into an observableArray, but that is wiped out when it is redefined as Object.days.  let's see where Objects.days is defined, and why it doesn't have a property called 'row'.

```
Objects = {days: [
  { day: 'Monday', row:[...] },
  { day: 'Tuesday', row:[...] },
  { day: 'Wednesday', row:[...] }
]};
```

Objects.days is an array.  Each item in the array has a property called row, but the array itself doesn't have a property called row.  So if you wanted to push something into the row array, you'd first have to figure out which one you wanted to push into - you have 3 of them - one for Monday, one for Tuesday, and one for Wednesday.  If you wanted to push onto Monday's array, you could do this:

```
alld[0].row.push(...);
```

Overall, I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here.  There are several problems with your markup and code, so the purpose of the code is a bit mysterious to me.  But here are some more things you should investigate:

You have a div as a child of a tbody.  You should only have tr's as children of a tbody, and td's inside of the tr's.  The div can then be a child of a tr.

You have a raw data-bind string that is inside of a div, like this (excluding other children of #Monday):

```
<div id="Monday">
  data-bind="template: { name: 'object', foreach: filterByDay('Monday') }""
</div>
```

I'm guessing that you meant to put data-bind as an attribute on something.  However, filterByDay isn't defined anywhere.

I see this line of code, where you use ko.mapping:

```
var cont = ko.mapping.fromJS(Objects);
alld = ko.observableArray();
alld = Objects.days;
```

cont is never used anywhere, and alld ends up as an array (not an observableArray).  I'm guessing that you meant to do something like this instead:

```
var cont = ko.mapping.fromJS(Objects);
alld = cont.days;
```

This would cause alld to be an observableArray with the data that comes from Objects.

I mentioned earlier that you have these two lines of code:

```
alld = ko.observableArray();
alld = Objects.days;
```

The first line is completely useless, as the observableArray you create in the first line is wiped out when you assign something different to alld.  This same pattern exists several times in your code.

What is drow?  drow is alld.row - this is undefined, as just discussed, so you can't call it with the new keyword as if it is a constructor.

What is self?  You never define self.  Typically when working with knockout, you'll put this at the top of your viewmodel:

```
var self = this;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Im very thankful for your analise and advices. That bring a much more sunshine into my work)

But I still cant push data into needles row-array/
Changes that I makes by your advices works:
`cont = ko.mapping.fromJS(Objects);
  alld = cont.days;`

Looks like it works fine, but I still cant figure out how to push some data into needles row array. I have a similar inputs field for each object of days-array, which should push data only into one  
corresponding array. I updated theme with jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/uhtshka/BWxm7/

Comment: 1. define alld as self.alld.  2. Save the viewmodel in a variable so you can access it from javascript.  3. Push to the row array inside alld on the viewmodel.  Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tlarson/BWxm7/4/

Comment: already did that. But if I define self.alld html didnt show even data from days-array:
http://jsfiddle.net/uhtshka/BWxm7/5/

Comment: You had infinite recursion: new ViewModel() was calling newViewModel().  Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/tlarson/BWxm7/9/.  I also created separate val1/val2/etc. properties for each day.

Comment: So much thanks to you!
But what is a debugger in add function?

Comment: Oops.  You can remove that - that kicks off the javascript debugger in your web browser.